# LLVM-IR Get Struct Element Pointer

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm building LLVM-IR with the C API and have a pointer to the following struct type:

```
{ i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, [1 x i64] }
```

That is, several `i8` pointers and an array of long integers, currently of size one but this will change in the future.

I want to access the element in the array at index `7`, and my current understanding is that I should be able to do this with a call to `LLVMBuildStructGEP` on the pointer to the struct, passing index `7`, and then a call to `LLVMBuildGEP2` on the returned address with `i64` as the type and `0` as the index.

This method doesn't flag up any problems when passing the module to `LLVMAnalyseModule`, but if I dump the bitcode of the module and then run `llvm-dis` on the file, I get the error:

```
llvm-dis: error: Explicit gep type does not match pointee type of pointer operand
```

Which I've isolated down to the second GEP on the address of the array returned from the first struct GEP.

For some additional information, I've noticed that if I replace the first struct GEP with a regular GEP taking the struct type as an argument, and then pass the struct type to the second GEP on what should be the `i64` array address, `llvm-dis` will not complain, but then subsequent loads or stores will be working with the wrong types so this is obviously not a real solution.

Comment: Looks like you are taking these indexes for GEP: [7, 0]. But imho you need to take such indexes: [0, 7, 0]. https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#why-is-the-extra-0-index-required

Comment: If issue is not fixed somehow still, can you give some code to reproduce? My knowledge of C API is terrible:( With code it will be easier :)

Comment: Using a single GEP with 0,7,0 works, although I'm unable to get separate GEP's or struct GEP's to work in the same index order, but I guess it doesn't matter too much. I would had posted code but this is actually part of a wider project and being used through python bindings, so it's not so straight forward to glance at! Thanks for the help.

Comment: The way GEPs work can feel a bit unintuitive. To split [0, 7, 0] you would need to add an extra 0 at the start of the new GEPs, as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. So, answering here.
As you see, you need to first get zero index, after than indexes 7 and 0.
The reason is simple to explain.
Let's see an example why extra zero is needed:

```cpp
char A *a = new A[123];
```

First index which is zero in your case can be used in arrays, but in your case it is a pointer to single element. In the case of array it can be not zero.

Anyway, I am not so clever about LLVM C APIs. Please don't kill me for that :D